# Comparing differences in Excel

Tags: excel

I need a formula in Excel to:

1. Compare a Quantity value from a Part Number on Sheet 1 to a Quantity value from a Part Number on Sheet 2.
2. If there is a difference between the two Quantity values, I need the Quantity value on Sheet 1 to be replaced with the Quantity value from Sheet 2 (and the cell be highlighted yellow if this is even possible). If there is not a difference, I need it to be left alone (and possibly be highlighted green if possible).

I think VLOOKUP might be the path I need to go down.

Comment: As you want to check and replace the very cell you are checking this will need to be vba.

Comment: Yes, the correct solution will likely be something along the lines of "=VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet2'!A:C,3)" with conditional formatting that highlights wherever column B on sheet 1 is different from column C on sheet 1.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think that while OP has asked to replace the data, my gut says it would be better to leave the original values in one column, and show the revised column beside it.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I agree that using another column to show the values and conditional formatting would be the best.  That way formulas can be used, I was making the statement that one cannot use formulas to change the very cell that one is testing without vba.  It it were me I would go your route.

Comment: Thank you both for your super quick help!